# Do I have a Recovery HD?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, filevault, recovery

I replaced my MBPs HDD with an SSD and put the HDD in the optical bay. Since then, I was missing the Recovery HD partition. That was still on Lion

Now I have upgraded to Yosemite, and running `diskutil list` gives this:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            490.8 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *120.0 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         119.2 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS SSD                    *118.8 GB   disk2
                                 Logical Volume on disk1s2
                                 89637DB5-6258-4E8A-A43B-814E61E23A8E
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

There are a couple of strange things here. Firstly, the SSD which was formerly /dev/disk0 has now moved to the end. I recently encrypted it, I don't know if that has anything to do with it. Second, the same drive is also listed above as /dev/disk1, evident by the  size of it (120GB Samsung EVO).
Third, there is a mysterious `Apple_Boot Boot OS X` partition on the HDD, I do not know what that is. But the point of this question is the presence of a `Recovery HD` partition on the HDD.

When I hold CMD-R at boot to start recovery, it puts me straight to internet recovery (unless I connect my backup disk), which probably means no recovery partition has been found. The Disk Utility GUI also does not show one (debug enabled)

[image]

I was under the impression that the installer creates a new recovery hd if not present, does the one for Yosemite not do that? And if no, why does `diskutil` list this Recovery HD which seemingly cannot be used for recovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the encryption process included in Yosemite there is a duplicate drive created in the space after the drive that was encrypted. If I'm entirely honest I don't know how that works or what its purpose is I just know that every encrypted machine in this situation has it. That being said you can see using diskutil that your ssd does have a recovery drive on it. Disk Utility no longer shows that in its list. So... not a lot of science to back it up but all signs point to a proper install having occurred and the recovery partition being right where it should be.

Comment: Well if that is the case, how do I use the Recovery partition? Diskutil says it's on the HDD, not on my SSD where the OS is.

Comment: diskutil says that the recovery exists at disk1s3 which is the ssd

Comment: Whoops, indeed, my bad. But as I said, I can't actually start recovery mode with it. Could it have to do with the encryption?

Comment: No recovery mode has now migrated exclusively to "remote/internet recovery" to avoid these kinds of issues. Being in the remote environment allows for you to run to some degree outside of your own sphere of influence and because of that you can do things like wipe your boot drive without danger of bricking because you can just clean install from there. Separately, from the remote install it will allow you to select your recovery partition to boot from and recover.